# "sudo gem install rails" not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

i have ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux] and gem 2.1.11 installed.I type sudo gem install rails into the command line, I get the following error message

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
SSL_connect returned=6 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read finished A (https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rails-4.0.2.gemspec.rz)``
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three things:

- That sounds like very much like you're using an outdated OpenSSL certificate file. Use `gem update --system` to update your RubyGems system gem. More details **[here](http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html)**.
- The version of Ruby you're using (1.9.3p194) is old and has several security problems. Upgrade to **1.9.3p484**: https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/
- Consider using a Ruby environment manager so that you don't have manage all this yourself. [`chruby`](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby) and [`rbenv`](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) are good choices once because they won't mangle your `cd` command when you change directories.

Comment: @EARashel You're welcome! If you feel this is the correct answer, I encourage you to click the checkmark to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Fedora 19 x86-64 on which is installed latest ruby and rails.

Do you specifically need old versions of ruby and rails? 
Ruby 2 and rails 4 are better/more secure. Latest tutorials from Michael Hartl and Agile Web Dev use these? There are too many ancient tutorials cluttering up learner space.
Have you got latest version of RVM installed?
Have you read the tutorials?
One can use RVM to install rails like this:

rvm get stable to get the last rvm versión

rvm install 2.0.0 to install ruby 2.0

rvm use 2.0.0 to use ruby 2.0

gem install rails - to install rails 4.0

RVM is your friend. Google is your friend.

Comment: i am learning rails from Agile Web Development with Rails, 4th Edition(beta version).in this book, they are using rais 3.0.3 . if i use rails 4.0,isn't there would be any problem?